# How to copy key/value from one modal to another modal

Tags: javascript, angular

i have two interface

```
export interface HalfPackage {
Chair?: String
Table?: String
Laptop?: String }
```

and

```
export interface FullPackage {
Chair?: String
Table?: String
Laptop?: String
Mouse?: String
KeyBord?: String }
```

i have only `FullPackage` class object and i have to assign that object to `HalfPackage` 's empty Object

i already try like that

```
...
let objHalfpkg : HalfPackage = {} as HalfPackage;
objHalfpkg = objFullpkg as FullPackage;
...
```

but when i print `objHalfpkg`,  i got all key/value of `objFullpkg`
, i can manualy remove that extra key from `objHalfpkg`,

```
delete objHalfpkg.Mouse
delete objHalfpkg.KeyBord
```

but is there any another way to get only that key from `FullPackage` which is available in `HalfPackage`.

Comment: Instead of having two unique interfaces, consider using polymorphic interfaces: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Pick<Type, Keys> utility type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys

```
interface FullPackage {
 chair: string;
 table: string;
 laptop: string;
 mouse: string;
 keyboard: string;
}

type HalfPackage = Pick<FullPackage, "chair" | "table" | "laptop">

const objHalfPackage: HalfPackage = {
 chair: "the chair",
 table: "the table",
 laptop: "the laptop",
};

objHalfPackage; //const objHalfPackage: HalfPackag
```

You could also alternatively use the `Omit<Type, Keys>`:

```
interface FullPackage {
 chair: string;
 table: string;
 laptop: string;
 mouse: string;
 keyboard: string;
}

type HalfPackage = Omit<FullPackage, "keyboard" | "mouse" | "laptop">;
```

which removes the types you don't want in the new type `HalfPackage`